# Illegal string offset in foreach

Tags: php, loops

I'm trying to loop in the second array with this code

```
        <?php 
        foreach ($categories[1] as $category_cat) { ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $category_cat['href']; ?>"><span><?php echo $category_cat['name']; ?></span></a></li>
        <?php } ?>
```

And I get the "Illegal string offset in..." error. I know that addind the [1] the the foreach might be the error but how I could make the loop in the second array then ?

Array content

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      'name' => string 'Brands' (length=7)
      'children' => 
        array (size=12)
          0 => 
            array (size=3)
              ...
          1 => 
            array (size=3)
              ...
          2 => 
            array (size=3)
              ...
          3 => 
            array (size=3)
              ...
          4 => 
            array (size=3)
              ...
          5 => 
            array (size=3)
              ...
          6 => 
            array (size=3)
              ...
          7 => 
            array (size=3)
              ...
          8 => 
            array (size=3)
              ...
          9 => 
            array (size=3)
              ...
          10 => 
            array (size=3)
              ...
          11 => 
            array (size=3)
              ...
      'column' => string '1' (length=1)
      'href' => string 'url here' (length=78)
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      'name' => string 'Catégories' (length=11)
      'children' => 
        array (size=7)
          0 => 
            array (size=3)
              ...
          1 => 
            array (size=3)
              ...
```

Comment: What does `$categories` contain ?

Comment: `var_dump($categories);` with show us array details

Comment: Added the array content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try to loop `$categories[1]['children']`:

```
foreach ( $categories[1]['children'] as $category_cat ) { }
```

Comment: God dammit, nice call. Thanks